# converting timestamp with time zone to localtime postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I having trouble figuring out how to convert the stored timestamp to whatever the local time zone so for example i have this query

```
SELECT INTO result string_agg(concat_ws(' - '
            ,sampleid
            ,starttime
            ,stoptime)
        ,'|')
FROM (
Select "ID" as sampleid,
 to_char("StartTimestamp",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as starttime,
to_char("EndTimestamp",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as stoptime from "Samples" ORDER BY starttime DESC) res;
```

even though the "StartTimestamp" is of type `timestamp with time zone` I don't know how to convert it to local time zone that the system is in.

Comment: Maybe it's already in local time -- but you stored the wrong time into the database?

Comment: no, let's say that i record a lot of records in arizona time, then I go to new york when i call that query i want it to return the time with the time zone in new york

Comment: May i recommend that you ensure that all times recorded in the database are UTC based. You may decide to record as addition information, the local time. Time conversion from UTC to local time is possible for any previous date and time. To show UTC times in the web browser then this link may be useful: http://thoughtworker.in/2011/10/15/local-time-in-browser/

Comment: @RyanVincent `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` *is* stored in UTC, converted to/from the time zone in the `TimeZone` system variable on load and store.

Comment: Sadly, there are rather more 'failure modes' when displaying local dates and converting input dates, than i like ;-/ I live in the UTC zone and DST confuses me when displaying date and times! ;-/

Comment: @CraigRinger : thanks for clarifying that. I agree that using TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE format will help to prevent a lot of confusion later.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `AT TIME ZONE` operator - or just set the `TimeZone` system variable.

```
thetimestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Perth'
```

This works with UTC offsets too, but be aware that PostgreSQL uses the ISO-8601 standard for UTC offsets.

See [Timezones](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) in the PostgreSQL docs. Note in particular the paragraphs about timezone formats, and  the paragraph:

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations west of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive timezone offsets are east of Greenwich.

Comment: how would i use the at time zone in my query ..?

Comment: @UbaldoQuintero I showed that above. See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html